# Need physic and path finding for JavafX 2D game

Tags: 2d, javafx-2, game-physics

i'm developing a strategic 2D game in JavaFX 2 and i need some basic physic and path finding for my game.

Would you plz give some tips and useful link to implement this 2.

tanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people have [integrated Box2D+JavaFX](http://thisiswhatiknowabout.blogspot.com/2011/11/hello-world-jbox2d-with-javafx-20.html) using a [Java port of the Box2D physics engine](http://www.jbox2d.org).

Michael Henrichs created a [JavaFX library for Inverse Kinematics](http://blog.netopyr.com/2013/03/06/javafx-library-for-inverse-kinematics-2-0/).

[Anton Epple created a small game framework for JavaFX](http://jayskills.com/blog/2013/01/09/writing-a-tile-engine-in-javafx/) which includes path finding for objects displayed within a tile engine.

The best place to and get tips and discuss these topics is probably the [java-gaming.org forums](http://www.java-gaming.org)

Comment: They are useful links, tanx @jewelsea